# How to check which files have been downloaded in some particular folder in C#.net?

Tags: c#, .net, file, system.io.file

How to check which files have been downloaded in some particular folder in C#.net ? The files are kept by other application and not by the current .Net application.

Comment: Are you wanting to check what files have been downloaded in the directory? You can use `System.IO` and list all contents of a directory. What have you tried? Where is your code? Are there errors? If there are errors, what line is causing it? Your questions seems better fit to be a [Search](https://www.google.com/) rather than a question.

Comment: It's not a typical programming issue.

Answer (score 0):

## region File Info

```
        System.IO.DriveInfo di = new System.IO.DriveInfo(@"C:\Users\abc\Desktop\FileDownload");
        Console.WriteLine(di.TotalFreeSpace);
        Console.WriteLine(di.VolumeLabel);

        // Get the root directory and print out some information about it.
        System.IO.DirectoryInfo dirInfo = di.RootDirectory;
        Console.WriteLine(dirInfo.Attributes.ToString());

        // Get the files in the directory and print out some information about them.
        System.IO.FileInfo[] fileNames = dirInfo.GetFiles("*.*");


        foreach (System.IO.FileInfo fi in fileNames)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("{0}: {1}: {2}", fi.Name, fi.LastAccessTime, fi.Length);
        }
```

// How to check if my files have been downloaded or still in progress of downloading.

Comment: Now I want to check , which files have been downloaded or not.  Using something like fi. How to doit. Or any other option available. .